# Django Angularjs 405 method not allowed. thinkster.io tutorial

Tags: django, angularjs, http-status-code-405

I am running through the tutorial found at:

https://thinkster.io/brewer/angular-django-tutorial/

I have gotten about 1/3-1/2 way through it. I am now testing it to see if it will register a user. It will not, every time I submit the form it gives me `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/accounts/ 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)`, I have ran back through the same tutorial half a dozen times to see where my mistake is but I can't seem to find it.

I'm not %100 positive where the problem is so I will post the most likely code files that could be the issue.

`authentication/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets

from authentication.models import Account
from authentication.permissions import IsAccountOwner
from authentication.serializers import AccountSerializer


class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(),)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            account = Account.objects.create_user(**request.DATA)

            account.set_password(request.DATA.get('password'))
            account.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Account could not be created with received data.'
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`static/javascripts/authentication.service.js`

```
/**
* Authentication
* @namespace thinkster.authentication.services
*/
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('thinkster.authentication.services')
        .factory('Authentication', Authentication);

    Authentication.$inject = ['$cookies', '$http'];

    /**
    * @namespace Authentication
    * @returns {Factory}
    */
    function Authentication($cookies, $http) {
        /**
        * @name Authentication
        * @desc The Factory to be returned
        */
        var Authentication = {
            register: register
        };

        return Authentication;

        ////////////////////

        /**
        * @name register
        * @desc Try to register a new user
        * @param {string} username The username entered by the user
        * @param {string} password The password entered by the user
        * @param {string} email The email entered by the user
        * @returns {Promise}
        * @memberOf thinkster.authentication.services.Authentication
        */
        function register(username, password, email) {
            return $http.post('/api/v1/accounts/', {
                username: username,
                password: password,
                email: email
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

`static/templates/register.html`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <h1>Register</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <form role="form" ng-submit="vm.register()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="register__email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="register__email" ng-model="vm.email" placeholder="ex. john@notgoogle.com" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="register__username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register__username" ng-model="vm.username" placeholder="ex. john" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="register__password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="register__password" ng-model="vm.password" placeholder="ex. thisisnotgoogleplus" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the last:

`static/javascripts/register.controller.js`

```
/**
* Register controller
* @namespace thinkster.authentication.controllers
*/
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('thinkster.authentication.controllers')
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];

    /**
    * @namespace RegisterController
    */
    function RegisterController($location, $scope, Authentication) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.register = register;

        /**
        * @name register
        * @desc Register a new user
        * @memberOf thinkster.authentication.controllers.RegisterController
        */
        function register() {
            Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.username);
        }
    }
})();
```

And, if that is not enough code, the project is also stored at: https://github.com/Taylor-Allred/thinkster-django-angular-boilerplate

I apologize for the wall of text/code, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the (unacceptably) delayed response! Not sure how I missed your questions, but I suppose a late answer is better than no answer.

If you look at your `urls.py` file, you will notice that you have two catch-all routes. Please remove the first one. The catch-all route must always be the last route in the `urls.py` file specifically for the reason you're experiencing this bug.

Here is what is going on:

When you make the request `POST /api/v1/accounts/`, Django is matching this against the first catch-all route in your `urls.py` file. This forwards the request to `IndexView` where the request expects to file a `post()` method. `IndexView` has no `post()` method, so the request fails with a status code of `405`.

Even though this is a very late response, I hope this helps you.

Feel free to comment on this answer if I haven't been clear!

P.S. olsonk has a point about register accepted arguments in a way that is incompatible with your code. Also, some time has passed since I wrote the tutorial. In this time, DRF (Django REST Framework) has updated and so that code may not work as-is.

Comment: i have followed the same tutorial to create a registration method in in django and the angularJs, but unfortunately i can't access the localhost:8000/register  url ,i am facing a error here which is  **"name 'IndexView' is not defined"** indication the urls.py file where **url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index')** , existed. i am really disappointed.

Comment: I'm sorry that you're disappointed. My guess is that there is a missing import statement for `IndexView`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain this will do the trick, but I did notice one potential issue - your `RegisterController`'s `register()` method sends your arguments in a different order from your `Authentication` service's `register()` method. Your service expects to receive (username, password, email), but your controller sends (email, password, username).

I was also encountering a 405 error on the tutorial, but my mistake related to my `authentication.service` posting to `'/api/v1/register/'` instead of `'/api/v1/accounts'`. Once I had that working, I then had to add some more imports into `authentication/views.py` - `from rest_framework import status` and `from rest_framework.response import Response`.

I'm fumbling my own way through learning this stuff as well, and this is my first response on StackExchange, so I apologize if this is not helpful/does not entirely fix your problem.

Comment: I appreciate the response, I will give this a try later tonight.

Comment: Just FYI - I wrapped up the tutorial today and have it (almost completely) working; only issue right now is that posts sometimes don't render on profile view. Project is at [https://github.com/olsonk/thinkster-django-angular-boilerplate.git](https://github.com/olsonk/thinkster-django-angular-boilerplate.git). Hope it's helpful - I found several errors throughout the template that took quite a long time to find and fix, so it can serve as a double-checking source.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue but when I was testing new post submission.

After hunting through my code, I finally found this in my `posts.service.js`:

```
function create (content) {
        return $http.post('/api/v1/posts', {
            content: content
        });
}
```

You'll notice there's a `/` missing from the POST request. I changed it to:

```
return $http.post('/api/v1/posts/', ...
```

And now everything is working again.